# How do I validate a TextBox with a RegularExpression based on a DropDownList Selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, textbox

I would like validate a Textbox based on a Dropdown List with regular expression. I would like to validate a credit card number based on the card type selected by the dropdown list.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<table runat="server">
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Credit Card Type"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Visa" Value="Visa"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="MasterCard" Value="Mastercard"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Card Number"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td> 
    <td><asp:CustomValidator ID=CustomValidator1 runat="server" ErrorMessage="Incorrect card, please re-renter!" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator></td>      
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandName="Submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And my other code:

```
protected void CustomValidation1_ServerValidate(object Source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string expression = "";

    switch (DropDownList.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "Visa":
        expression = "^(4)([0-9]{15})$";
        break;
        case "MasterCard":
        expression = "^(5[1-5])([0-9]{14})$";
        break;
    }
}
```

So when I select on `MasterCard` on the Dropdown List and input numbers in the textbox. I would like to be validate with the regular expression `^(5[1-5])([0-9]{14})$`. And also when I select `Visa` on the Dropbox List and input numbers in the textbox, it will validate with the expression of `^(4)([0-9]{15})$`.

Here it would be for MasterCard:

Matches:
`5212345678901234`

Does not Match:
`1234567890123456`

Comment: post some sample strings which should be matched and which shouldn't

Comment: @AvinashRaj what do you mean by "post some sample strings which should be matched and which shouldn't"?

Comment: so you want code  not regex...

Comment: @AvinashRaj i have edited the question, is this much more clearer?

Comment: you need to add end pattern http://regex101.com/r/yM4iP6/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do would be as follows:

Instead of a `custom validator`, you will need to add a `regular expression validator` at the end of the `textbox` and with the process of code behind for your `drop down list`, use if statements that will allow the change to persist. Also your `drop down list` needs to perform `Auto Post Back` setting to `True` to allow the changes to occur.

Here is the ideal code behind for your question:

```
protected void DropDownList1_OnIndexChanged(object Source, EventArgs args)
{


    if (DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text == "Visa")
    {
        RegularExpression1.ValidationExpression = "^(4)([0-9]{15})$";
        else
        RegularExpression1.ValidationExpression = "^(5[1-5])([0-9]{14})$";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it so:

Declare 2 RegExpValidators one for VISA-Regex, another for MasterCard-Regex. 
Declare `OnSelectedIndexChanged`-Method for the `DropDownList` in code behind.
In this method enable the correct validator based on the `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList` and disable the onother one.

Comment: yes, of course, i thougth u want to have the RegExValidator :)

Comment: can u explain me what aure u doing with your expression, so it can not work, u have to set `isValid` `true` or `false`. Take look at [CustomValidator Titorial](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/). So u have to proff the value with your expression and say is it valid :)

Comment: ok, let's look at the method that you have told me before, how do i take on that approach?